# How to resolve TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BufferedReader

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, tkinter, typeerror

I create a gui using python tkinter. I got stuck at a point where i want to open a text file and then store the data of file into a list. I tried the following code:

```
root = Tk()
def open_f(): 
    global file
    file = askopenfile(mode ='rb', filetypes =[('All Files','*.*'),
                  ('pdf files', '*.pdf'),('txt Files','*.txt')])
    print('Selected:', file)
    
button1 = Button(root, text ="Select text file",command=open_f)
button1.grid(row=9,column=1,pady=5)
l1=[] 
TextFile = file
# open the file for data processing
with open(TextFile,encoding="utf8") as IpFile:
    for j in IpFile:
        l1.append(str(j).strip())   
       
root.mainloop()
```

But i got the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-39-6eb178acbcd6>", line 216, in dataProcessing
    with open(TextFile,encoding="utf8") as IpFile:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BufferedReader
```

May be my approach is not right so, how to resolve this?

Comment: I got different error `NameError: name 'file' is not defined` on the line `TextFile = file` when running your code.

Comment: May be because file is in function but i made it global then why it is not defined?

Comment: Then you better update your code so that the mentioned exception can be reproduced.

Comment: The code represent what i want to do and i also explain it in question, if you have any other approach to do this then tell me

Comment: According to your code, when `TextFile = file` is executed, `file` is not created yet because `open_f()` has never been executed.

Comment: it will executed after button pressed

Answer (score 0):

`askopenfile()` actually opens a file for you. You have the following options

Read from the file as is and then close it

```
file = askopenfile()
for j in file:
    # do your stuff
file.close()
```

Use the preferred open statement in a similar fashion

```
with askopenfile() as f:
    # do your stuff
```

Get the path of the file and open it later. Notice the different function.

```
file = askopenfilename()
with open(file) as f:
    # do your stuff
```

Comment: i tried this, gives the error **NameError: name 'file' is not defined**

Comment: It's because you only select a file when a button is pressed, but you try to read the file regardless at the execution of the script. Either you put the file reading logic in `open_f()`, or in its own function that is trigged by another button (in which case you should check whether a file has been chosen before you try to read it).

Comment: Yeah i get it. Thanks for your help.